# Innerhtml nao funciona

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer um exemplo de javascript muito simples mas o `innerhtml` não está sendo reconhecido.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

            <title>Pagina com Javascript</title>
            <script src="meujavascript.js"></script>
            <!-- Versao do JS <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript1.8.5"></script> -->

    </head>

    <body>
    <!--
    <p id="paragrafo">texto em javascript</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="mostrar()">Teste</button>
    -->

    <p id="valores">[valores]</p>

    </br></br></br>

    <button type="button" onclick=adicionar(1,2)">Mensagem</button>

    </body>

</html>
```

Função em javascript:

```
function adicionar(parcela1, parcela2)
{
    //esta função adiciona dois valores
    var resultado = parcela1 + parcela2;
    var test document.getElementById("valores");
    test.innerhtml = resultado;
}
```

HTML muito simples só para praticar.

Meu exemplo de javascript. Quero continuar a praticar mas não sei porque não esta a funcionar o innerhtml.. Alguem pode ajudar ?

Comment: `innerhtml` deve ser com `HTML` grandes. => `innerHTML`

Answer (score 6):

Apenas 2 erros no código JavaScript:

- `var test document.getElementById("valores");`: Depois de `'var test'` poderia ter sido declarado **`'='`** (inicializador), **`','`** (próxima variável), **`';'`** ou uma quebra de linha, mas ao invés disso apareceu um nome.
- O seu código é interpretado e executado no caso-sensitivo, por isso `test.innerhtml` não será equivalente à `test.innerHTML`. `test.innerHTML = ...` é o setter que você quer usar.

Para resolver os problemas do código declarei um inicializador na frente da definição da variável `'test'` e troquei `test.innerhtml` por `test.innerHTML`, que pode ser o getter/setter `HTMLElement#innerHTML` nos navegadores de hoje.

```
function adicionar(parcela1, parcela2) {
    var resultado = parcela1 + parcela2;
    var test = document.getElementById("valores");
    // Se a propriedade test.innerHTML tem um setter em test,
    // chama a função do setter, se não então re-define
    // a propriedade test.innerHTML sensivelmente
    test.innerHTML = resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
var test = document.getElementById("valores"); // falta o '='
test.innerHTML = resultado                     // 'html' em maiúsculo
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgRGJZ?editors=1010

Comment: Mas não é o que ele esta fazendo? No enunciado da pergunta, tem o mesmo código..

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni Na verdade não. O parser é *case-sensitive*: `test.innerhtml` é diferente de `test.innerHTML`.

Comment: A bom, não tinha reparado nisso kkkk ^^.. +1

Comment: Você nem percebeu o `=` faltando ali na variável test né!

Comment: verdade @SampaioLeal ..

Answer (score 0):

Letras maiúsculas em innerHTML e aspas

```
    <head>

    <title>Pagina com Javascript</title>
    <script src="meujavascript.js"></script>
    <!-- Versao do JS <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript1.8.5"></script> -->
    <script>
    function adicionar(parcela1, parcela2)
    {
    //esta função adiciona dois valores
    var resultado = parcela1 + parcela2;
    var test = document.getElementById("valores");
    test.innerHTML = resultado;

    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <!--
    <p id="paragrafo">texto em javascript</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="mostrar()">Teste</button>
    -->

    <p id="valores">[valores]</p>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <br><br><br>

    <button type="button" onclick="adicionar(1,2)">Mensagem</button>

    </body>

    </html>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/0zixeHtok0L3QORwmggy?p=preview

Comment: Bem vindo ao stack overflow em português, por favor traduza sua resposta.